# SimpleJDBCCall class parameter passing

Tags: java, spring, stored-procedures, jdbctemplate

I have a stored procedure in y db which is on MYSQL server. And when I try to call it, it gives the error:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Incorrect
>   number of arguments for PROCEDURE thu.productGetter; expected 2, got 0
>     at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.doTranslate(SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.java:95)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:73)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:1137)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.call(JdbcTemplate.java:1173)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.AbstractJdbcCall.executeCallInternal(AbstractJdbcCall.java:378)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.AbstractJdbcCall.doExecute(AbstractJdbcCall.java:363)

Java code is:

```
SimpleJdbcCall jdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(getJdbcTemplate())
                                    .withSchemaName("thu")
                                    .withProcedureName("productGetter");

    jdbcCall.addDeclaredParameter(new SqlParameter("maxPrice", Types.DOUBLE));
    jdbcCall.addDeclaredParameter(new SqlParameter("minPrice", Types.DOUBLE));

    Map<String, Object> params=new HashMap<String, Object>();
    params.put("maxPrice", maxPrice);
    params.put("minPrice", minPrice);


    jdbcCall.execute(params);
```

And the stored procedure db code is:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `productGetter`(IN maxPrice double,minPrice double)
BEGIN
        ...    
END$$
```

I have checked plenty of examples and could not find any solution for my problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: The error you are receiving is telling you that you have not passed enough parameters to it. Check to see if the params are getting set correctly in your `params Map`.

Comment: they are anf it actually says that it did not pass any parameter, not less.

Comment: Enable DEBUG logging and see in logs what parameters and what values are passed to the stored procedure. `AbstractJdbcCall.executeCallInternal` has [this kind of logging](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-jdbc/src/main/java/org/springframework/jdbc/core/simple/AbstractJdbcCall.java#L369).

Comment: definitely, I have looked at source code of jar and found that in the end the callparameters list is empty.

Comment: There would be the alternative `jdbcCall.execute(maxPrice, minPrice);` too.

Answer (score 5):

I've experienced the same issue after upgrading from mysql 5.1 connector to 6.0.6 and the way to solve is just to add : `.withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess()` in this way :

```
SimpleJdbcCall jdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(getJdbcTemplate())
                                    .withSchemaName("thu")
                                    .withProcedureName("productGetter")
                                    .withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess();

    jdbcCall.addDeclaredParameter(new SqlParameter("maxPrice", Types.DOUBLE));
    jdbcCall.addDeclaredParameter(new SqlParameter("minPrice", Types.DOUBLE));

    Map<String, Object> params=new HashMap<String, Object>();
    params.put("maxPrice", maxPrice);
    params.put("minPrice", minPrice);


    jdbcCall.execute(params);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same message about missing parameters but it turned out that it was the schema name that was wrong

Answer (score 0):

You could try **MapSqlParamterSorce** instead.

```
SimpleJdbcCall jdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(getJdbcTemplate())
                                    .withSchemaName("thu")
                                    .withProcedureName("productGetter")
                                    .withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess();

jdbcCall.addDeclaredParameter(new SqlParameter("maxPrice", Types.DOUBLE));
jdbcCall.addDeclaredParameter(new SqlParameter("minPrice", Types.DOUBLE));

MapSqlParameterSource source = new MapSqlParameterSource();
source.addValue("maxPrice", maxPrice);
source.addValue("minPrice", minPrice);

jdbcCall.execute(source);
```